# How to call stored procedure multiple time in binary tree

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursive-query

It's a binary tree table. I have two fields as leg1 and leg2.if leg1 is != empty and leg2 is empty, i can call the procedure recursively. and viceversa. but when leg1 and leg2 !=  empty how to call the procedure recursively.(CALL `getFinal11`(`next_leg2_name`, `result`); CALL `getFinal11`(`next_leg1_name`, `result`);

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getFinal11`(IN `param_name` VARCHAR(255), OUT `result` VARCHAR(65535))
BEGIN
  DECLARE `next_leg1_name` VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE `next_leg2_name` VARCHAR(255);

  SELECT `leg1` INTO `next_leg1_name` 
  FROM `matrix` 
  WHERE `username` = `param_name`;

  SELECT `leg2` INTO `next_leg2_name`
  FROM `matrix`
  WHERE `username` = `param_name`;

  IF `next_leg1_name` <> '' AND  `next_leg2_name` = '' THEN
    CALL `getFinal11`(`next_leg1_name`, `result`);
    SET `result` := CONCAT(`next_leg1_name`, ',', IFNULL(`result`, ''));
  END IF; 

  IF `next_leg2_name` <> '' AND `next_leg1_name` = '' THEN
    CALL `getFinal11`(`next_leg2_name`, `result`);
    SET `result` := CONCAT(`next_leg2_name`, ',', IFNULL(`result`, ''));
  END IF;  

  IF `next_leg2_name` <> '' AND `next_leg1_name` <> '' THEN
    CALL `getFinal11`(`next_leg2_name`, `result`);
    CALL `getFinal11`(`next_leg1_name`, `result`);
    SET `result` := CONCAT(`next_leg2_name`, ',', IFNULL(`result`, ''));
    SET `result` := CONCAT(`next_leg1_name`, ',', IFNULL(`result`, ''));
  END IF;  

  IF `next_leg2_name` = '' AND `next_leg1_name` = '' THEN
    SET `result` := '';
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```